# couldn't get values from sqlite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my application I want save data in database.

Here is my code of SQLiteHelper

```
public class UserSqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final String LOGCAT = "JBF/SQLite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jbfjsonEntityDB";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "jbfjsonEntity";

    private static final String KEY_JSON = "json";
    private static final String KEY_URL_PATH = "url_path";
    private static final String KEY_TIME = "added_on";

    public UserSqliteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "dictionarysqlitehelper.db", null, 1);
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_JSON + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_TIME + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp, "
                + KEY_URL_PATH  + " TEXT )";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME ;
        db.execSQL(query); onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addJsonEntity(JsonEntity jsonEntity) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_JSON, jsonEntity.getJson());
        values.put(KEY_URL_PATH, jsonEntity.getUrl_path());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public JSONObject getJsonByUrl(String url) {
        String json = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
//            Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, KEY_URL_PATH + "=?", new String[]{url}, null, null, null);
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + KEY_URL_PATH + "='"+url+"'";
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (c == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                c.moveToFirst();
                json =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_JSON));
                if (json != null) {
                    return new JSONObject(json);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When I call from my activity this

```
UserSqliteHelper sqliteHelper = new UserSqliteHelper(SplashActivity.this);
sqliteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
sqliteHelper.addJsonEntity(new JsonEntity(STRING_CONFIGS_URL,response.toString()));
System.out.println("json  ==== "+sqliteHelper.getJsonByUrl(GET_USER_INFO_URL));
```

I always got this error

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong in here. Why I can't get my database values?

Answer (score 1):

The query didn't match any data. `moveToFirst()` fails and the cursor doesn't point to a valid row. You should check that `moveToFirst()` succeeds - it returns a boolean.

Why it didn't match any data is because you're storing and retrieving data by different keys: `STRING_CONFIGS_URL` and `GET_USER_INFO_URL`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of c==null try c.getColumnCount == 0